# ::root not responding in @media, scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, frontend, media-queries

in the app.css file i have saved media breakpoint variables

```
 :root{
    
      --max-width-phone: 37.5em;
      --max-width-tab-port: 56.25em;
      --max-width-phone-tab-land: 75em;
      --max-width-desktop: 112em;

    --shadow-box:
  1.6px 4.9px 4.9px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.096),
  3.8px 11.4px 11.4px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.138),
  6.9px 20.5px 20.4px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17),
  11.4px 34px 33.9px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  18.8px 56.1px 55.8px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.232),
  32.8px 98px 97.6px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.274),
  71px 212px 211px -18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37)
;
  
}
```

but when i try to use these breakpoint in another document the media query won't pick  them.

```
.container{
    max-width: 120rem;
    margin: 8rem auto;
    background-color: var(--colour-white);

    box-shadow: var(--shadow-box);
    min-height: 95vh;
    font-size: 4rem;

    @media (max-width: var(--max-width-phone)) {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
};
```

but the box shadow is working fine. will someone please provide feedback as to what i am doing wrong!!

Comment: You can't use variables for breakpoints in CSS

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.css`? or `.scss`, why are you trying to link a CSS file to an SCSS file? use SCSS everywhere then you can link files to each other and import variables. However, to try and answer your question:

You should define the variables in SCSS like this:

`$variable: value:`

then use it like so:

`background-color: $colour-white;`

This is especially true and the only way to use variables with breakpoints, `var(--some-width)` doesn't work with breakpoints, not even with regular CSS. Instead just use `$some-width`.